# ORM and DAO design patterns

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, dao

I would like to use Dao pattern with hibernate orm but i m confused about how to create data transfer objects.

For example if I have a users table and orders table, 1 to many relation.
With hibernate my UserDTO contains all User columns + OrdersDTO. OrdersDTO will be populated by hibernate with lazy load, so if i say UserDao.getUserByPk(1) i get all user data and all his orders and i send this object to the view.

If i change Hibernate to JDBC then I have a problem, if i say UserDao.getUserByPk(1) I get only user data, for his orders i need to do OrdesDao.getOrdersByUserId(1), but in my view i have only one object.

So my question is how can I use ORM functionality(lazyload for example) but in the same time if i change the datasource my business logic won't be affected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a "dao" abstraction layer to do this. Your service layer, which contains the business logic, should call the dao layer to fetch any DTOs. The dao layer should contain contracts/interfaces and implementation (based on Hibernate, JDBC or others). You should be able to configure your dao implementation selection via some externalized configuration (to prevent a re-compile after any change in dao layer implementation selection).

View Layer > Service Layer > Dao Layer (HibernateImpl or JdbcImpl or etc.) > fetch data from db into DTOs and return it to caller.

Comment: So you are saying that in my userdao after i get my hibernate user object i should map it to a dto pojo and return it to service ? Can t i directly return the hibernate user object ?

Comment: You should not pass on Hibernate objects up or down the layer because you are planning to use Hibernate and plain JDBC alternatively. Image if you did passed Hibernate objects across the layer and you try to switch from Hibernate to plain JDBC, you have a very strong dependency on Hibernate Framework classes, which will not allow you to remove Hibernate JAR(s) from your project.

Comment: ok i agree with you on this one but how can i map my hibernate object to a pojo and i refer to lazy load objects (join tables ). If i won t use lazy load and return just the simple pojo then orm will lose an important important function

Comment: If you are using Hibernate XML based mapping then your POJOs are not invaded by the Hibernate Annotation API and thus in this case your POJOs are good to be treated as DTOs and you can pass them across the layers. BUT, if you are using Hibernate Annotations in your POJOs for mapping, I would recommend to move to XML mapping and if not then you have to convert your Hibernate Annotated POJOs to your DTO and then return the DTO to the caller code. In this particular case you can write a generic conversion mechanism using APIs like Apache Common BeanUtils, etc.

Comment: You forgot Model layer,,,